# How can enter in a open session using Spring Websocket Handler?

Tags: java, websocket, ocpp

I'm testing a Ocpp Server comunication using Spring Websocket. The handshake works well, I can interact with the client when a station send a message (BootNotification,StatusNotification...). But sometimes I need to send things with the server (request remote transaction, get informations, etc), without the station send first.
How can I access a open session (example: ws:localhost:8080/central/station01) with another service?

My Wesocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new MyHandler();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/central/**")
        .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
        
    }   
}
```

My WebSocket Handler:

```
public class MyHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler implements SubProtocolCapable {
    
    

    private final String[] subProtocols = {"ocpp1.6", "ocpp2.0"};
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepo;
    
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) {
        Global.id="";
        Global.session="";
        Global.client="Close";
        System.out.print("\n Connection Close \n"+"Session: "+session.getId()+"\n");
        session.getHandshakeHeaders();
        System.out.print("session enabled"+session);
        
    }
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session)
            throws Exception{
        Global.id=session.getId();
        Global.session=session.getUri().toString();
        Global.client="ok";
        
        
        Client aa= new Client(null,session.getId(),session.getUri().toString(),"ok","");
        System.out.print("\n Connected \n"+"Session: "+session.getId()+"\n");
        
        System.out.print(session.getUri());
        
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session,WebSocketMessage<?> message)  throws Exception {
        //WebSocketHttpHeaders expectedHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
        System.out.print("\n "+message.getPayload());
        Integer id=0;
        Global.ocpp=Global.ocpp+" \n "+message.getPayload().toString();
        
        ZonedDateTime data = ZonedDateTime.now();
        BootNotificationResponse stat=new BootNotificationResponse("Accepted",data.toString().substring(0,data.toString().length()-"[America/Sao_Paulo]".length()),300);
        JSONArray mm=new JSONArray((message.getPayload()).toString());
        id=(int )mm.get(0)+1;
//      session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(message.getPayload().toString()));
//      System.out.print("\n Remote: "+session.getRemoteAddress()+"\n");
        JSONObject ss=new JSONObject(stat);
        System.out.print(session.getHandshakeHeaders());
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        
        ja.put(3);
        ja.put(mm.get(1));
        //
        ja.put(ss);
//      System.out.print("\n"+message.getPayload()+"\n");
//      System.out.print(mm.get(2)+"\n");
        Client dados=new Client(null,Global.id,Global.session,Global.client,message.getPayload().toString());
        clientRepo.save(dados);
        if(mm.get(2).equals("Authorize")) {
            
            JSONArray nob = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject iii=new JSONObject(new Auth(new AuthorizeResponse("1233434","ddfd","Accepted")));
            nob.put(3);
            nob.put(mm.get(1));
            nob.put(iii);
            System.out.print(nob);
            //[2,"4","Authorize",{"idToken":{"idToken":"111111","type":"ISO14443"},"evseId":[1]}]
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(nob.toString()));
        }
        if(mm.get(2).equals("BootNotification")) {
            System.out.print("Boot \n");
            
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(ja.toString()));
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public List<String> getSubProtocols() {
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(subProtocols));
        return Arrays.asList(subProtocols);
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do plenty of things to send command from your side to station.

1. When station connect to your server, you need to keep that session
   in a Map with chargepointId probably.
2. If you would like to send
   command then use that session then use websocket instance to send
   command to station.
3. To initiate Step-2, you need to have service or
   API to initiate it.

Should you need information, follow this URL: https://github.com/ChargeTimeEU/Java-OCA-OCPP